# Using Sed and Echo to get filenames from folder and apply to first line respectively

Tags: shell, sed, cmd, echo, geojson

I have been trying to use echo to pull geojson filename and insert it into their geojson code as a variable. Since echo puts text at the bottom of the files, I tried to create my first geojson by: 
`for /R %f in (*.shp) do echo %~nf = >> "%~dpnf.geojson"`. 
This gets the .shp name and creates a geojson with the variable. I then used ogr2ogr to create the geojson info from the same .shp using this code:

```
for /R %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 "%~dpnf.geojson" "%f"
```

The problem with this cmd line is that the `"%~dpnf.geojson"` replaces my variable geojson due to the same name. The reason why I tried it using this method is if the geojson combined via same names, the variable name would show on top of the file instead of below. Any tips?

My second method was via sed. I have gotten certain text to show on top of the geojson but the problem is that I figure out how to call its own filename to the top. This gets the filename but uses echo, which brings the text to the bottom.

```
for /R %f in (*.geojson) do echo %~nf = | sed "s/.*\///"
```

Code below spits out filename depending on how many geojsons reside in the folder:

```
for /R %f in (*.geojson) do sed -i "1i filename" "%~dpnf.geojson"
```

I would like filename to be a dynamic text corresponding with the the actual filename. Thanks in advance for the people taking their time to help me.

Comment: There's a lot of commands that I don't recognize. You're trying to create a variable that is a list of filenames inside a folder?

Comment: Doesn't look like `bash` to me. Please tag the question with the correct shell (type`echo "$0"` to print the name of your shell).

Comment: I am trying to display one text name of their respected file name.

Comment: This is batch.  DOS batchfile.  I think.  That tag is [batch-file]